# Trying to share a socket with an obejct in the parent class

Tags: java, oop, sockets, applet

can anyone enlighten me?  I was trying to access a socket in an object belonging to a parent class (main applet class).  I wish I could make this more consise for you.  Bit of a mouthful but maybe my source will explain a little further.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class SocketsC {

    Socket clientsocket;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader in;

    public void SocketsC()  {

    }

    public void connectSock()   {

        try {

            clientsocket = new Socket( "localhost", 9900 );
            out = new PrintWriter(clientsocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( clientsocket.getInputStream()));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            System.exit(1);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

class AccessSock    {

  AccessSock()  {

        // Here is where I am trying to access the socket from the mysocks object
      mysocks.out.println( "working" );  // This doesn't work...
  }

}

public class main extends JApplet {

    static SocketsC mysocks;

    public void init() {

      createApp();
    }

    public void createApp() {

        SocketsC mysocks = new SocketsC();
        AccessSock sendtext = new AccessSock();
    }
}
```

TYIA
-Roland

Comment: what error you are getting? what does _it doesn't work mean_ ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't scroll down to see the rest of your code. In your specific case `main.mysocks.out.println(...)` should work.

Comment: mysocks can't be resolved

Comment: Your line of code in `AccessSock` - `mysocks.out.println( "working" );`, accesses a non-existent variable (as your error *clearly* states). To be honest, this class doesn't seem to be worth much, it has no logic within it.

Comment: None of those variables should be `static.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have defined `mysocks` as static, you need to use `className.variable` to access it.

```
static SocketsC mysocks;
```

Change this:

```
mysocks.out.println( "working" );
```

to

```
main.mysocks.out.println( "working" );
```

This should work. Since there is no variable called `mysocks` in your class. It is throwing error.

Comment: That works! Tyvm my friend.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

From your code `mysocks.out.println( "working" );` I understand that you want to access `println` method
So you can directly do that using

```
SocketsC.out.println( "working" );
```

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
 public class main extends JApplet {
    //existing code

    public void createApp() {
      mysocks = new SocketsC();
      AccessSock sendtext = new AccessSock(mysocks);
  }
```

and

```
class AccessSock    {

  AccessSock(SocketsC mysocks)  {
    // Here is where I am trying to access the socket from the mysocks object
    mysocks.out.println( "working" );  // This doesn't work...

  }
}
```